# Estimation of a combinatorial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory

Fix a non-negative integer $t\in\mathbb N\,$. I am interested in the following sum
$$S(t) \,:=\, \sum_{m}\,2^m\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m\leq t}k_1\cdots k_m$$
where clearly $1\leq m\leq t$ and $1\leq k_i\leq t$ for $i=1,\dots,m$.

Is it possible to compute $S(t)$ in a close form? Or at least what is a good upper bound for $S(t)$?

Comment: Where does this sum come from? What have you tried? What is a good upper bound for you?

Comment: This sum is related to the number of certain connected shapes of given size on the square grid. By a good upper bound I mean a sharp one: the optimal one or close to that. I tried some numerical simulations and it seems $S(t)\leq 4^t$ (not optimal but not far). It would be nice to prove this inequality.

Comment: By convexity of the exponential, it holds $k_1\cdots k_m\leq (\frac{t}{m})^m$.
But then what is a bound for $\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m\leq t}1$? $t^m$ is not sharp enough.
I am not sure that this is the right way to obtain an inequality like $S(t)\leq 4^t$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us assume that the variables $k_i$ could take also the value $0$ this does not change the value of $S(t)$ (but in my relations this makes the sums meningful), so for every $t\geq 1$:
$$\begin{align} S(t)&=&\sum_{m=1}^t 2^{m} \sum_ {k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m\leq t}k_1k_2\cdots k_m\\
&=&\sum_{m=1}^t 2^m\sum_{k_1=0}^t  \left(\sum_ {k_2+\cdots+k_m\leq t-k_1}k_2\cdots k_m \right)k_1\\ 
&=&\sum_{k_1=0}^t  \left(2+\sum_{m=2}^t 2^{m}\sum_ {k_2+\cdots+k_m\leq t-k_1}k_2\cdots k_m \right)k_1\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{t}(2+2S(t-k))k \end{align}$$

This is true also for $t=0$. Now if we consider $f(x)=\sum_{t=0}^{+\infty}S(t)x^t$ we have:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{t=0}^{+\infty} S(t)x^t&=&\sum_{t=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{t}(2+2S(t-k))kx^t \\
&=&2\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}(1+S(i))jx^{i+j}\\
&=&2\left(\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}(1+S(i))x^i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}jx^{j}\right)
\end{align}$$
In the previous lines we used the Cauchy product formula for series and knowing the power series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $ gives us:
$$f(x)=\frac{2x}{(1-x)^2}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$
and this yelds:
$$f(x)=\frac{2x}{(1-x)(1-4x+x^2)} $$
which gives the exact [first values](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2F%28%281-x%29%28x%5E2-4*x%2B1%29%29).

Now if we calculate the coefficient of this fraction we find:

$$S(t)=\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6}\left( (2+\sqrt{3})^t+(2-\sqrt{3})^t\right) -1$$ and because $|2-\sqrt(3)|< 1$ we can conclude the asymptotic formula:
$$S(t)\sim \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6}(2+\sqrt{3})^t -1$$

and we can prove that $S(t)\leq 4^t$ and maybe there will be an expression of $S(t)$ using the function the nearest integer and the previous asymptotic formula.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which gives an explicit formula!
Can you please explain how you obtain the functional equation for $f$?

PS. I made some edits to corresct typos (in particular $t$ instead of 2 in the last step of the eq for $S$), please check them.

Comment: Sorry I have one more question: how do you obtain a explicit expression for the coefficients of $f(x)$, that are $S(t)$? I mean, how do you guess the general form of the coefficients in the Taylor expansion of $f$?

Comment: The best [way](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B2x%2F%28%281-x%29%281-4x%2Bx%5E2%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D)

Comment: Very smart! thanks :)

Comment: I posted a new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178020/computation-of-a-two-variable-combinatorial-function , maybe you are interested