# Computation of a two variable combinatorial function

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For every $t\geq1$ and $1\leq k\leq t-1$, $G(t,k)$ is a combinatorial sum satisfying the following recurrence:
$$G(t,k) = 2t-1 + \sum_{h=1}^{t-k-1} G(t-k,h)\, (2k+2h-1) \;.$$

Is it possible to compute $G(t,k)$ explicitly?
In [Estimation of a combinatorial sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173321/estimation-of-a-combinatorial-sum) a similar problem is solved, but here I have difficulties to deal with the two variables $(t,k).$

*Edit:* Actually I am just interested in the explicit value of
$$G(t):= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{t-1} G(t,k) \;;$$
I don't know whether this simplifies the problem.

Comment: You need to give us the first values of $G(0,k)$, is it true that $G(t,k)=2t-1$ when $t\leq k+1$.

Comment: If $k\geq t$ then $G(t,k)=0$. If $t=2$ then $G(t,1)=2t-1=3$.

Comment: I think I managed to find something, but the computation is long. I will check tomorrow.